# Selecting Specific record among multiple records in association Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, activerecord

I have a model called **User** and associated model **Message**. So user can have many messages. I have 4 columns in messages table named `sent_at`, `opened_at`, `clicked_at` and `email id`.

In message table `email id` is not unique. User would have sent multiple emails. So for a user in messages table he can see same email multiple times.

eg: If `user_id` is 7 and I need to find out the recent opened emails using the association. I need the records of all the users who have opened the mail recently.

I used this:

```
User.find(7).messages.select(*).group(:email_id).having("max(opened_at)")
```

But its giving men the error.

Any help is largely appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what you storing in opened_at ??

Comment: `.select('*')`. * is a special character in Ruby known as [the splat](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). Even at that I doubt you need it since AR will select all the columns anyways.

Comment: Also if the column is named `email_id` you should do `.group(:email_id)` not  `:email`.

Comment: In opened at I am storing the time at which mail was opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after doing lot of research

```
a = User.find(7).messages.order("opened_at,clicked_at”).group_by(&:email_id)
```

This will return hash. I will convert this to array using a.to_a and from there I can access the entire active record